# Non english chars in browers url

Tags: asp.net

/bg/продукти/81-skin-toning-mask

How to get that show like that in browser url path, instead of

/bg/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8/81-skin-toning-mask

1. HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/bg/продукти/81-skin-toning-mask") - same result (unreadable chars for продукти part)
2. HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode("/bg/продукти/81-skin-toning-mask") - doesn't even render link properly (strange)
3. HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("/bg/продукти/81-skin-toning-mask") - same result (unreadable chars for продукти part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://www.example.com/bg/продукти/81-skin-toning-mask
```

Is an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier).

```
http://www.example.com/bg/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8/81-skin-toning-mask
```

Is the correct [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) representation of the above IRI.

Both are valid and will work equally well as the value of an `<a href>` in modern browsers.

It is normally considered kinder to old browsers to use the URI version, however when you do this IE (bizarrely) displays the URI version in the address bar instead of the nice IRI version, even though it is the same address and IE sends the same request to get it. Also some characters IE will never display unencoded (though Russian works for me).

So if you care more about making your address bar look nice in IE than supporting older pre-IRI browsers, just write the non-ASCII string straight out to the page, only escaping out-of-band ASCII characters. Your pages should be served as UTF-8 for this to work reliably over different IE settings, but really today everything you do should be UTF-8 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of allowable characters in Uniform Resource Locators (URLs) in [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) does not contemplate non-latin (non US-ASCII) character sets.

Sorry, it's terribly chauvinistic, but consider how difficult it would be to support all alphabets!?

Comment: Not terribly difficult if it had been designed that way from the beginning and there weren't thousands of different programs installed on millions of servers that depend on the non-Unicode-capable standard.

Comment: Non-ASCII characters are perfectly valid in URIs. You just have to UTF-8 and then URL-encode them. The form where you see the characters themselves is called IRI and is supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: So, living in an English-speaking country means I haven't been exposed to these. But when I go to the link Daniel provided, and click on one of the links there, I can see Cyrillic in the URL. **Never seen that before!** Curse the accident of my birth..

Answer (score 0):

How about this link:

[http://rts.rs/page/stories/ci/story/8/Култура/178211/Представа+и+трибина+о+квислинзима+на+Битефу.html](http://rts.rs/page/stories/ci/story/8/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0/178211/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%83.html)

it contains lots of non-latin chars